# Mongo find() query is not working fine

Tags: mongodb

below is the mongo document,

```
db.south.find({station:"Stourton"})
{ "_id" : ObjectId("572cca5a9c850445fc6c3122"),
  "line" : { "map" : "north_image.jpg", "name" : "north" }, 
  "dep" : { "dep_timing" : 
                           [{ "time" : "09:50" }, 
                            { "time" : "11:50" },
                            { "time" : "12:50" },
                            { "time" : "13:50" },
                            { "time" : "14:50"},
                            { "time" : "15:50" },
                            { "time" : "16:50" }, 
                            { "time" : "17:50" },
                            { "time" :"18:50" }, 
                            { "time" : "19:50" }, 
                            { "time" : "20:50" },
                            { "time" : "21:50" },
                            { "time" : "22:55" } ], 
 "route" : [ { "station" : "CitySquare" } ] }, 
 "station" : "Stourton" }
```

I am using this query to extract the time greater than or equal to "09:50",

```
> db.south.find({dep:{dep_timing:{"time":"09:50"}}})
```

But no result is output. I am new to Mongodb so please help. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query should be like this:

```
db.south.find({ "dep.dep_timing.time": "09:50"})
```

And will return all the documents that have `{"dep":{"dep_timing":{"time":"9:50"}}}`

Have a look at the [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-documents/)